# pytest.ini value not being set correctly

Tags: python, config, pytest, ini

Trying to set an option in a pytest.ini file dynamically. The option testpaths determines what directories pytest will gather tests from. I want to give users the ability to select test directory `a` or `b`.

**conftest.py**

The first hook creates a parser option. 
The second hook pulls the parser option reads the value and adds the testpath to the testpaths option under the config object.

```
@pytest.hookimpl() 
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """Creates a parser option"""

    # Allows the user to select the test suite they want to run
    parser.addoption("--suite", action="store", default="None"
                     , choices=['a', 'b']
                     , help="Choose which test suite to run.")

@pytest.hookimpl()
def pytest_configure(config):
    print("Determining test directory")
    suite = config.getoption("--suite")

    if suite == "a":
        config.addinivalue_line("testpaths", "tests/a")

    elif suite == "b":
        config.addinivalue_line("testpaths", "tests/b")
```

So if i run `pytest --suite a` it should load all tests under the a test suite. It does not. It loads all tests like the option doesnt exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is being set correctly. Your problem is that at the time `pytest_configure` hooks are being called, the ini file values and the command line args are already parsed, so adding to the ini values will not bring anything - they won't be read again anymore. In particular, the `testpaths` value from ini file is already processed and stored in `config.args`. So we can overwrite `config.args` instead:

```
@pytest.hookimpl()
def pytest_configure(config):
    suite = config.getoption('--suite')

    if suite == 'a':
        config.args = ['tests/a']
    elif suite == 'b':
        config.args = ['tests/b']
```

---

#### Edit

An example of accessing the config in your tests (via `pytestconfig` fixture):

```
def test_spam(pytestconfig):
    print(pytestconfig.getini('testpaths'))
    print(pytestconfig.args)
    suite_testpaths = set(pytestconfig.args) - set(pytestconfig.getini('testpaths'))
    print('testpaths that were added via suite arg', suite_testpaths)
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I assume that the args we supply to the config are assumed to be the test path as default? How would it know if i supplied other args?

Comment: @DrewAckerman: I guess you can, since the ini values are not removed after configuration. You can always grab the config (it can be always accessed via `pytestconfig` fixture) and compare the `args` with the ini values. See the updated answer!